# Boost Interprocess named_mutex as a class member

Tags: c++, boost, locking, mutex

I have a class designed as a wrapper around some boost shared memory. When I try to put a named_mutex as a class member and initialize it in the constructor, I get compilation errors. Here is the relevant code:

```
   template< class T > class SharedMemoryVal
   {
      public:
         SharedMemoryVal( const std::string &name, bool readOnly );

         SharedMemoryVal( const SharedMemoryVal& other )
         {
            name = other.name;
            mutexName = other.mutexName;
            permissions = other.permissions;
            shm = other.shm;
            mutex = boost::interprocess::named_upgradable_mutex( boost::interprocess::open_or_create, mutexName.c_str() );
         }

         const SharedMemoryVal& operator=( const SharedMemoryVal& other )
         {
            if( this == &other )
               return *this;

            name = other.name;
            mutexName = other.mutexName;
            permissions = other.permissions;
            shm = other.shm;
            mutex = boost::interprocess::named_upgradable_mutex( boost::interprocess::open_or_create, mutexName.c_str() );
         }

         int8_t GetVal( T *val );

         int8_t SetVal( T val );

         virtual ~SharedMemoryVal();

      private:
         std::string name;
         std::string mutexName;
         boost::interprocess::mode_t permissions;
         boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object shm;
         mutable boost::interprocess::named_upgradable_mutex mutex;
   };

   using namespace boost::interprocess;

   /**
    * Construct new shared memory data value
    * @param[in] name - Name of shared memory segment
    * @param[in] readOnly
    */
   template< class T > SharedMemoryVal< T >::SharedMemoryVal( const std::string &name, bool readOnly )
   {
      // Set name
      this->name = name;

      // Create mutex
      mutexName = this->name.append( "_mutex" );

      /* GETTING AN ERROR HERE */
     /*  error: \u2018boost::interprocess::named_upgradable_mutex::named_upgradable_mutex()\u2019 is private*/
      mutex = named_upgradable_mutex( open_or_create, mutexName.c_str() );

      //Create a shared memory object.
      if( readOnly )
      {
         permissions = read_only;
         shm = shared_memory_object( open_only, name.c_str(), read_only );
      }
      else
      {
         permissions = read_write;
         shm = shared_memory_object( create_only, name.c_str(), read_write );

         // Set size
         shm.truncate( sizeof(T) );

      }
   }

   template< class T > SharedMemoryVal< T >::~SharedMemoryVal()
   {
      shared_memory_object::remove( name.c_str() );
      named_upgradable_mutex::remove( mutexName.c_str() );
   }
   /**
    * Return current data value
    * @return current data value
    */
   template< class T > int8_t SharedMemoryVal< T >::GetVal( T *val )
   {
      int8_t retVal = -1;
      //Map the whole shared memory in this process
      mapped_region region( shm, permissions );

      // Get data pointer
      T *data = static_cast< T * >( region.get_address() );

      // Lock
      {
         // This will only lock if someone else is writing.
         // Multiple processes can read at the same time
         sharable_lock< named_upgradable_mutex > lock( mutex );
         // If there wasn't a problem getting the data
         if( data != NULL )
         {
            *val = *data;
            retVal = 0;
         }
      }
      return retVal;
   }
   /**
    * Set shared memory data value
    * @param[in] val - value to set
    */
   template< class T > int8_t SharedMemoryVal< T >::SetVal( T val )
   {
      int8_t retVal = -1;
      //Map the whole shared memory in this process
      mapped_region region( shm, permissions );

      // Get data pointer
      T *data = static_cast< T * >( region.get_address() );

      // Do lock
      {
         // Lock will always be unlocked at the end of this block
         scoped_lock< named_upgradable_mutex > lock( mutex );

         // If we got the data OK
         if( data != NULL )
         {
            *data = val;
            retVal = 0;
         }
      }

      return retVal;
   }
```

I'm getting an error in the constructor where I create a lock object, but I can't figure out why. I read that I must define my own copy constructor and assignment operator, and I've done that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because the mutex member has to be initialized.

This occurs via the default constructor. Which is in this case private. Therefore you get the error (about the default constructor of boost::interprocess::named_upgradable_mutex named_upgradable_mutex() being private).

What actually would happen with the code you have is: The mutex member would be initialized using its default constructor before entering the body of the SharedMemoryVal constructor. Then in the body you would assign a newly constructed object to the mutex member. Which even if inefficient it would work provided the default (parameterless) constructor for named_upgradable_mutex would be public (having it private makes sense since default constructing the mutex with no name is senseless).

I reccomend you read Scott Meyers's Effective C++ (and More effective C++). If you don't have them I reccommend you buy them. In Effective C++ chapter 1, Item 4 'Make sure objects are initialized before they're used' you get a similar explanation about what happens if you assign in the ctor body to your member variables (default construction+assignment as explained above) versus initializing them in the initializer list (only construction).

In More effective C++ you have two items. **Item 12:** Prefer initialization to assignment in constructors.

and

**Item 13:** List members in an initialization list in the order in which they are declared.
(this relates to the note below about initialization order) in more detail.

Some online material illustrating the above described behavior:  [Why preffer member initialization over assignment?](http://nirbhay.in/2013/07/member_initialization_list/)

To solve the problem move the construction of the mutex to the initializer list. More about member initializer lists here [Member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

Like:

```
template< class T > SharedMemoryVal< T >::
SharedMemoryVal( const std::string &name, bool readOnly ) : 
    mutexName( name.append("_mutex") ),
    mutex (open_or_create, mutexName.c_str() ) 
        {
        }
```

**Note:** Please pay attention to the initialization order and make sure mutexName is initialized before mutex. 
Counterintuitively if you declare the mutexName member after mutex in the SharedMemoryVal class declaration then mutexName will be uninitialized when calling the mutex constructor with it, since the initialization occurs in the order of declaration in the header, not in the order from the member initializer list. In your case you declared mutexName before mutex so you would be just fine. Just don't move its declaration after the one for mutex in the header... Thought I should mention this also.